# Popup window in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a hyperlink field in a grid view as below :

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField  Text="Analyze" />
```

When I click on it,a popup window should appear where I can enter details.
My question is how do I go about it ? I am a beginner so please explain in detail. I am using C# and Asp.net.

Comment: <asp:HyperLinkField  Text="Analyze" />

Comment: How should you want it to display using the [Javascript, jquery](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) or using the [AjaxControlToolkit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: I don't know either of them :P so,whichever is easier.

Comment: Depends on how and what you want to do with it ? Try anyone of the approach which suits you.

Comment: I want to enter few details which I will then update in a database

Comment: Which one is better for this purpose ?

Comment: If you want more data security and reliability then go with AjaxControlToolkit otherwise use  Javascript, jquery it will make it lightweight

Answer (score 0):

You need here from the client side to call a javascript that opens the window.

The window that you going to open can be a different page call inside some iframe, or just a set of hidden controls that you needs them for that page.

To open this windows you can use the asp.net toolkit

http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

or the HightSlide http://highslide.com/

or use the jQuery dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

or other javascript library.

Here is a simple example of highslide, you just need to have this line on the edit hyperlink. Then you must have that page `detailspagetoedit.aspx` to been able to make the edit...

```
<a href="detailspagetoedit.aspx?id=2" 
   onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe' } )" >edit</a>
```

and a tutorial about: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html

Comment: How do I use this with Hyperlink field in GridView ?

Comment: @TRY123 You need to make some test your self, find some tutorial, see how its works... I am not able to give you general code more than the one I have write, after that its a full tutorial how its done. Its not so simple.

Comment: I got this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514346/popup-window-in-asp-net.But I am not able to understand fully where to paste that code.I pasted it in .aspx file but it is not working.

Comment: @TRY123 If you can not make your edit in a window, then make a link to a new page that make the edit. Start from that its more easy. Its not so simple what you try to do...

Comment: @TRY123 Found some tutorial about : http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html